# Comparing two columns of different length in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to implement vlookup type functionality in R. I have two data frames -
Id column has unique values.

```
# DataFrame1 - df1
Data   ID       C1        C2      C3 
R1     ax       12        33      11
R2     ay       11         2       0
R3     az        3         3       0
R4     ar        2         3       1
R5     ag        2         3       1

# DataFrame2 - df2
Id
ax
ay
```

I want to get all the data and get its count from DataFrame1 for which there is a match between Ids from DataFrame2 and DataFrame1.

Output should be -

```
Data ID C1 C2 C3
R1   ax 12 33 11
R2   ay 11  2  0
```

and its count will be 2

Also, is this possible without merge function?

Comment: check `%in%` or `match`.

Comment: @Joe: Re your request for an inexact match: since your question at the moment doesn't actually ask for that solution, you should search SO and if you cannot find an answer post another question with an example that actually raises the possibility of an inexact match. I know that I have answered a similar question before but it's possible that you won't find it the search term "fuzzy matching". Try "partial" or "inexact" as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To subset your first dataframe by your second, then count the number of rows:

```
z=df1[df1$ID %in% df2$Id,]
count=nrow(z)
```

Comment: Will this function do the exact match? I mean if we are having ID ax in one data frame and ID axh in second data frame, will this method identify the difference?

Comment: @Joe You might want to look into "fuzzy matching" if you don't have exactly matching ids.

Comment: The `which` is superfluous. Just using `df1$ID %in% df2$Id` as the `i` argument would be more efficient.

Comment: Thank you all! I do have exact ids. %in% does check for the exact match and this worked out for me

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("ID" = "Id")) # Because Id columns names are different
inner_join(df1, df2) # If the Id columns were the same
```

Using `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('SELECT * FROM df1 JOIN df2 USING (ID)') # Not case sensitive
```

Output:

```
  Data ID C1 C2 C3
1   R1 ax 12 33 11
2   R2 ay 11  2  0
```